# how to access inside records of api

Tags: angular, webapi

```
this.service.getdata().subscribe((res) => {
  console.log(res);
  this.weatherData = res;
});
```

how can I print the 'name' in console, this image shows API
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i< this.weatherData.list.length ; i++) {
console.log(this.weatherData.list[i].name);
}
```